# Grab and save SVG File using selenium - C# Selenium chromedriver WinForm

Tags: winforms, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

I am writing WhatsApp tool in C# winform using Selenium ChromeDriver.
I have handled all operations like sending the message, clicking the attachment and all from WhatsApp web using Selenium ChromeDriver.

I want to read the WhatsApp web's QR Code which is in SVG format. I want to read the SVG File and convert and save as image in local.

I could save the QR Code using snapshot, but I don't prefer using this because I have to maintain vertical scroll position to bring full QR Code on screen.

So please help me save svg file image using chromedriver

Thank you.
-Ishrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the specific commands in Selenium, but can't you just:

- copy the SVG code via Javascript/a Selenium method
- then create a new .svg file in Java and save this copied svg code as the contents?